# Meta Tag's + OG + Twitter Card

Tags: magento-1.9, header, meta-tags, social-buttons

I added the following code to the head

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
<title><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
<meta name="author" content="Hope Collective" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://hopecollective.com/hope_collective_logo@3x.png"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl() ?>"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName() ?>"/>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@HopeCollect" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://hopecollective.com/hope_collective_logo@3x.png" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="125773904784788" />
<?php if($isResponsive){?>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<?php }?>
<?php $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
if ($product): ?>
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($product->getShortDescription()); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getProductUrl($product); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(300, 300); ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName() ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="product">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php echo $product->getName(); ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($product->getShortDescription()); ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(300, 300); ?>" />
<meta name="twitter:data1" content="$<?php echo number_format($product->getPrice(),2);?>">
<meta name="twitter:label1" content="PRICE">
<meta name="twitter:site" value="@HopeCollect">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="125773904784788" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Its pretty much working fine except for 2 issues with facebook debugger is not calling the correct product image (og:image). Its calling the default og:image which i added above if product part. But the code is working perfectly fine on twitter card validator. Its show the correct product image. Also the og:type comes as website for products.

Any idea where I'm going wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook probably reads the first occurrence of the tag. Simply move default image tag to the end of the code inside else clause.